# Overloading + and += operators in parent and child class in C++

Tags: c++, inheritance, operator-overloading, operators, abstract-class

Okay guys, this one has me confused not least because of how little info for this there is online...

Okay so lets say I have a parent and a child class as such:

```c++
   class ParentPlot
   {
      public:
         int a; 
         int b;
         datacontainer Events;


         friend ParentPlot& operator+(ParentPlot& plotA, const ParentPlot& plotB)
         {
            //add stuff
            return sumPlot;
         }
         virtual ParentPlot operator+=(const ParentPlot &plotB)
         {
            //+= stuff using 'this'
            return *this;
         }
   }

   class ChildPlot: public ParentPlot
   {
      public:
         int q;

      friend ChildPlot& operator+(ChildPlot& plotA, const ChildPlot& plotB)
         {
             //Static cast and add the parents.
            ParentPlot PlotACast = static_cast<ParentPlot>(plotA); //2 Static casts
            ParentPlot PlotBCast = static_cast<ParentPlot>(plotB);
            ParentPlot ParentSum = PlotACast + PlotBCast; //Add as ParentPlots
            ChildPlot BasePlot = ChildPlot(ParentSum);

            //Add child members
            BasePlot.q = plotA.q + plotB.q;

            return BasePlot;
         }
      ChildPlot& operator+=(const ChildPlot& plotB)
      {
          //How do I correctly implement this?
      }
   }
```

How am I supposed to correctly manage the addition and += of these classes? Every combo seems to give errors of some kind and I cannot get this to work. For example the method implemented above gives the following error:

"too few parameters for this operator function"

I have tried making ParentPlot an abstract class and then just implementing in the child class but then the addition operator breaks because I can't return a parent in the addition operator.

Technically ParentPlot will be abstract but will have many children which will need to be summed, and it has multiple members. Should I not implement an addition operator or += for the parent and only the children or am I missing something? Genuinly no idea the correct way to handle this. Any ideas would be helpful...

Thanks

Comment: `+` can't return a reference since it needs to create a new object. (Virtual operators is very often not as good an idea as you first think.)

Comment: shouldn't the += not return "this" which would be a reference?

Comment: `this` is a pointer, not a reference. `+=` is expected to return `*this` by reference, the modified object (you can work around the slicing issue there by not returning anything). Your `+`, on the other hand, is returning a reference to `BasePlot`, which is an automatic object and is destroyed when the function returns.

Comment: As a general rule of thumb, mutating operators - like `+=` - return a reference to the modified object, `*this`. Non-mutating operators - like `+` - return a new object by value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### 1. Fix your operator return types.

`operator +` should return a copy. `operator +=` should return a reference to `this`.

```
friend ParentPlot operator+(ParentPlot& plotA, const ParentPlot& plotB)
ParentPlot& operator+=(const ParentPlot &plotB)
friend ChildPlot operator+(ChildPlot& plotA, const ChildPlot& plotB)
ChildPlot& operator+=(const ChildPlot& plotB)
```

#### 2. Implement your `operator +` using `operator +=`

This little trick is makes your code DRY and it will make it easier to implement those extra operators.
Note that first parameter is taken by value, we need a copy that will be modified by `operator +=`.

```
friend ParentPlot operator+(ParentPlot plotA, const ParentPlot& plotB)
{
    return plotA += plotB;
}

friend ChildPlot operator+(ChildPlot plotA, const ChildPlot& plotB)
{
    return plotA += plotB;
}
```

#### 3. Implement child `operator +=`

Assuming that you already have `operator +=` for `ParentPlot`, you can use it in two ways:

```
static_cast<ParentPlot&>(*this) += plotB;
//or
ParentPlot::operator+=(plotB);
```

Then you add child-specific implementation and `return *this;` as usual.

#### Full code ([see it online](https://wandbox.org/permlink/0qBl91CbaEGRHqfE)):

```
class ParentPlot {
public:
    int a;
    int b;

    friend ParentPlot operator+(ParentPlot plotA, const ParentPlot& plotB)
    {
        return plotA += plotB;
    }
    ParentPlot& operator+=(const ParentPlot& plotB)
    {
        a += plotB.a;
        b += plotB.b;
        return *this;
    }
};

class ChildPlot : public ParentPlot {
public:
    int q;

    friend ChildPlot operator+(ChildPlot plotA, const ChildPlot& plotB)
    {
        return plotA += plotB;
    }
    ChildPlot& operator+=(const ChildPlot& plotB)
    {
        //static_cast<ParentPlot&>(*this) += plotB;
        ParentPlot::operator+=(plotB);
        q += plotB.q;
        return *this;
    }
};
```